# ember.js one-way binding

Tags: binding, ember.js

I have some one-way binding issues while trying to bind a value in my view to a value in my controller:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    value: 'my value'
});

App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'application',

    willInsertElement: function() {
        console.log('will insert element');
        console.log('value from controller > ', this.get('controller').get('value'));
        console.log('value > ', this.get('value'));
        console.log('completeValue > ', this.get('completeValue'));
    },

    valueBinding: Ember.Binding.oneWay('controller.value'),
    completeValueBinding: Ember.Binding.oneWay('App.ApplicationController.value')
});
```

"value >" returns the right value but "completeValue >" returns undefined (see jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/U29wV/7/)...

Comment: what is the difference between `valueBinding` and `completeValueBinding`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing the class `ApplicationController` not the actual instance.

You are already accessing the `ApplicationController` instance through the `controller` property of your view, so just use that for the binding:

```
valueBinding: Ember.Binding.oneWay('controller.value'),
completeValueBinding: Ember.Binding.oneWay('controller.value')
```

Which makes it identical to the `valueBinding`...